# How to create a unit test for a function that uses $filter 'date'

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-filters

I am writing a unit test for a function within my controller.

The function uses the $filter to format the date in 'yyyy-MM-dd' format.

However my karma script fails to run after the line on which the filter is used.

**Here's the function:**

```
$scope.myFunction = function (someDate) {

    var dateTo = new Date(someDate);
    var myDate = $scope.myDate;

    // Code fails after line below on unit test /////
    var searchdate = (filter('date')(myDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
    searchdate = serviceConvertISODate.convertDate(searchdate);        
}
```

In the example above, var myDate = 1405967947000 (epoc format)

**Unit test:**

```
describe('Validating functions within Controller', function () {        

    var scope, ctrl, filter, localServiceConvertISODate;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $filter, serviceConvertISODate) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new(),
        ctrl = $controller('MyController', {
            $scope: scope,
            filter : $filter,
            serviceConvertISODate : localServiceConvertISODate
        });                
    }));

    it('should test my function', function() {

        var dateTo = new Date("22 Sep 2014");
        console.log("********* dateTo = " + dateTo );

        var myDate = $scope.myDate;
        console.log("********* myDate = " + myDate );

        var searchdate = (filter('date')(myDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
        console.log("searchdate after filter = " + searchdate);

        searchdate = localServiceConvertISODate.convertDate(searchdate);            

    });
});
```

I can see through my logs:

```
dateTo is returning the correct new date

myDate is returning the correct myDate
```

However, applying the next line (filter), causes the test to break and no error is provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your code. You're passing the AngularJS `$filter` to your controller as `filter` for some reason (why?), which could work if your controller requests that injection, but then you try to use `filter` variable in your test code, where it's value is undefined. Set the value in your `beforeEach()` if you want to use it later:

```
filter = $filter;
```

Also, I'm not sure whether you're just debugging or if the provided code shows what you're trying to do. If the latter, note that the unit-test should test your unit from "outside". So it should really be calling your `$scope.myFunction` with some data and testing if the result fits your expectations. You don't copy the insides of your function to your tests.

Comment: thanks for the response, it makes sense however i am really new to testing, so aplogies. Are you able to provide code snippet? I get TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$filter('date')') when i try.

Comment: Have you read [the developer guide to unit-testing in AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing)? I'd start by using `$filter` in your code and removing `filter` alltogether.

Comment: if i remove filter and var searchdate = ($filter('date')(myDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')); i get the error  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $filter

Comment: $filter('date') isnt a filter i created.. Its an epoc conversion recommendation from the Angular site: $filter('date')(date, format, timezone) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: See my answer. If you remove `filter`, you still have to save `$filter` to a variable that's visible in your test, if you want to use it there. Variable visibility is basic stuff, try some debugging first before re-posting.

Comment: thanks, sorry i didnt see the second paragraph until a moment ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
describe('Service: myService', function () {

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  var myService, 
    httpBackend, 
    fromDate,
    toDate;

  var d = new Date();

  beforeEach(inject(function (_myService_, $httpBackend, $filter) {
    myService = _myService_;
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    fromDate = $filter('date')(new Date(d - 86400000 * 15), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    toDate = $filter('date')(d, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  }));

  // ...

}
```